# In Typescript, is it possible to override a superclass property's type without overriding the value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a superclass property with a generic type, e.g.:

```
class Super {
  static get foo(): Record<string, any> {
    return ...
  }
}
```

I thought I could override the type like this:

```
class Sub extends Super {
  static foo: SubType;
}
```

However, this sets `Sub.foo` to `undefined`. I want `Sub.foo` to maintain the same value, but have a new type. Is this possible?

The type for `Sub.foo` is different because `Super.foo` depends on other static properties of the subclass.

I think implementing an interface should work, but it'll be good to know if there's another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `declare` to avoid compiling the variable into the actual Javascript:

```
class Sub extends Super {
  declare static foo: SubType;
}
```

Comment: Documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier